# Serialize Params to store in Database for Logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am processing the payment and looking to dump the content i receive from the Gateway into my DB for logging.

```
@order[:payment_details] = params.to_json.to_s
```

Getting the following error

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Comment: i am not so familiar with ruby-on-rails  but it seems to be an error occurred due to data type miss match. may be while you are trying to assign a symbol to an integer variable/column vice versa.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that @order is an array - the keys must be integers. This sounds like you expected @order to be a hash or activerecord object - review where @order is created.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have no need to explicitly convert params to JSON just declare you params details as

```
serialize :payment_details
```

in your model it automatically serialize you params hash and on time of fetching deserialize your hash for reading.

An above error is due to you are trying to convert symbol i.e key in params to integer.